# Accurately testing Pypy vs CPython performance

Tags: python, performance, benchmarking, pypy

**The Problem Description:**

I have this custom "checksum" function:

```
NORMALIZER = 0x10000


def get_checksum(part1, part2, salt="trailing"):
    """Returns a checksum of two strings."""

    combined_string = part1 + part2 + " " + salt if part2 != "***" else part1
    ords = [ord(x) for x in combined_string]

    checksum = ords[0]  # initial value

    # TODO: document the logic behind the checksum calculations
    iterator = zip(ords[1:], ords)
    checksum += sum(x + 2 * y if counter % 2 else x * y
                    for counter, (x, y) in enumerate(iterator))
    checksum %= NORMALIZER

    return checksum
```

Which I want to test on both Python3.6 and PyPy performance-wise. I'd like to see if the function would perform better on PyPy, but I'm not completely sure, what is the most reliable and clean way to do it.

**What I've tried and the Question:**

Currently, I'm using `timeit` for both:

```
$ python3.6 -mtimeit -s "from test import get_checksum" "get_checksum('test1' * 100000, 'test2' * 100000)"
10 loops, best of 3: 329 msec per loop

$ pypy -mtimeit -s "from test import get_checksum" "get_checksum('test1' * 100000, 'test2' * 100000)"
10 loops, best of 3: 104 msec per loop
```

My concern is I'm not absolutely sure if `timeit` is the right tool for the job on `PyPy` because of the [potential JIT warmup overhead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13180954/771848).

Plus, the PyPy itself reports the following before reporting the test results:

```
WARNING: timeit is a very unreliable tool. use perf or something else for real measurements
pypy -m pip install perf
pypy -m perf timeit -s 'from test import get_checksum' "get_checksum('test1' * 1000000, 'test2' * 1000000)"
```

What would be the best and most accurate approach to test the same exact function performance across these and potentially other Python implementations?

Comment: Does that test (time) anything at all? It seems you only perform a setup and no real test command?

Comment: @MSeifert ah, I am an idiot, you are absolutely right. There was only set up there, I've updated the answer leaving the latter part of the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could increase the number of repetitions with the `--repeat` parameter in order to improve timing accuracy. see:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html

Answer (score 2):

It is not entirely clear what you are trying to measure. "Performance" can mean a variety of things depending on your use-case.

- Are you trying to measure raw speed of the function once everything is warmed up (JIT in particular but also library imports, file loading, etc...)? Then you probably want to `--repeat` a lot like Haroldo_OK suggested. With enough repetitions, the time spent in other parts of your code would become progressively "insignificant".
- are you measuring things for the sake of learning or for a real world use case? If the latter, it is probably a good idea to test your code under similar conditions (length of the strings you're passing to your function, number of iterations, warm/cold calling of your code...). My impression is that using the [python interface](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/timeit.html#python-interface) instead of the CLI would give you more flexibility to measure exactly what you're after.

Of note, [`timeit` turns off garbage collection](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/timeit.html#timeit.Timer.timeit), so if you're looking for "real world" measurements, maybe you want to turn it back on (see the link for how to do it).

If you're trying to improve the speed, using a profiler like [cProfile](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/timeit.html#timeit.Timer.timeit) which is supported by both Python3.6 and [pypy](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/timeit.html#python-interface) could help with isolating the code whose speed you want to measure?

I'm not actually answering your question, but I hope it helps :)