# Why PyPy considers "timeit" as unreliable tool for Python performance measurement?

Tags: python

PyPy warning about timeit:

```
(my-pypy-env) $ python -m timeit --setup "from simulation import benchmark" "benchmark()"
```

> WARNING: timeit is a very unreliable tool. use perf or
>   something else for real measurements ten loops, average of 7: 106 +-
>   0.383 msec per loop (using standard deviation)

Using perf:

```
(my-pypy-env) $ python -m perf timeit --setup 'from simulation import benchmark' 'benchmark()'
```

> Median +- std dev: 97.8 ms +- 2.3 ms

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PyPy displaying inaccurate benchmark results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13180740/pypy-displaying-inaccurate-benchmark-results)

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [PyPy displaying inaccurate benchmark results?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13180740/2344631) over on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

It seems to be that the JIT compiler is an unpredicatable overhead in the timing loops.